# Why is everything here pushed down, and am I adding any unnecessary code?

Tags: css

I am playing with h1 (I love you) and the pseudo classes before (the moon picture) and after (TO THE MOON AND BACK).

I think I managed to get it working, to do what I want it to do. I was curious to know if a h1 pseudo class could go in front of and behind the main element using z-index, if I could include an image, if I could rotate, etc.

But I am wondering why is it not at the top of the page? There seems to be a lot of padding there. And when I look at Chrome Developer Tools I cannot see the padding for pseudo classes so easily. Can anyone give me any hints? Also, am I including any unnecessary code?

```css
body {
  background: #201215;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.iloveyou {
  font-family: 'abril fatface';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: antiquewhite;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

.iloveyou::before {
  content: url(images/moon.png);
  z-index: -2;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -200px;
}

.iloveyou::after {
  content: 'TO THE MOON AND BACK';
  font-family: '';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: max-content;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="iloveyou">I love you...</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: but you should include your HTML also, you can make a snippet

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>I love you...</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=abril fatface' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <h1 class= "iloveyou">I love you...</h1>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: That is caused by `display: block` on the `::before`. It now has a height of 60px according to my browser, so it causes a 60px gap above the text.